# What is the meaning of second parentheses in front of "require()" function in JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, require

I just saw this line of code:

```
var FileStore = require('session-file-store')(session);
```

I understand the code up to second parentheses but can't understand what is the second parentheses in general? Why it hasn't `''` inside of it? Why the code uses it and how does it work?

Comment: Means you call `session-file-store` constructor with `session` as argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that earlier in your file, you've required and defined `session` (most likely Express Session). This means that you're requiring `session-file-store`, executing the function with the required `session`, and assigning the return value of that function to `FileStore`.